# Accessing Local files with a website

Tags: javascript, html, security

Is it possible to access/read local files by Javascript(combined with HTML) running in a website without user intervention ?

PS: I don't want to build a malicious website, I just want to know is it possible or not ? (debate between friend)

Comment: 1. Did you try it? That would tell you for sure. 2. Did you Google it? That would tell you, too.

Comment: Maybe, if somebody visits your page using IE5...

Comment: I saw this post : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. In this webpage it shows a way to read the file with file object. So I am thinking is it possible to create a file object

Comment: No - for obvious security reasons..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can only add fileselect-form input and then user can choose the file to read for javascript.